# LEFT JOIN with FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have 3 tables

```
Master {MasterID, Desc},
Detail {MasterID, DetailID, ItemID},
Items  {ItemID, ItemDesc})
```

I want to select Master, Detail (as SubElement in Master), Item (in same element of Detail)

```
SELECT Master.MasterID, Master.Desc, Detail.DetailID, Detail.ItemID, Items.ItemDesc
FROM Master
    LEFT JOIN Detail 
        LEFT JOIN Items 
            ON Detail.ItemID = Items.ItemID 
    ON Master.MasterID = Detail.MasterID
FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS
```

it gives result below:

```
<Master>
 <MasterID>1</MasterID>
 <Desc>Master1</Desc>
 <Detail>
  <DetailID>1</DetailID>
  <ItemID>1</ItemID>
  <Items><ItemDesc>ItemDesc1</ItemDesc></Items>
 </Detail>
</Master>
```

But my target is

```
<Master>
 <MasterID>1</MasterID>
 <Desc>Master1</Desc>
 <Detail>
  <DetailID>1</DetailID>
  <ItemID>1</ItemID>
  <ItemDesc>ItemDesc1</ItemDesc>
 </Detail>
</Master>'
```

How can I do that with best practice way?

Answer (score 3):

Make the detail and item description come back from a single query, like so:

```
SELECT 
    Master.MasterID, 
    Master.Desc, 
    Detail.DetailID, 
    Detail.ItemID, 
    Detail.ItemDesc 
FROM 
    Master 
    LEFT JOIN (
        select
            d.MasterID,
            d.DetailID,
            d.ItemID,
            i.ItemDesc
        from
            Detail d
            left join items i on
                d.itemid = i.itemid
    ) Detail ON
        Master.MasterID = Detail.MasterID
FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for xml path` like this.

```
select m.MasterID,
       m.[Desc],
       (select d.DetailID,
               d.ItemID,
               i.ItemDesc
        from Detail as d
          inner join Items as i
            on d.ItemID = i.ItemID
        where d.MasterID = m.MasterID
        for xml path('Detail'), type)
from Master as m
for xml path('Master')
```